# I arrive at an AttributeError while trying to import the pybel module

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, attributeerror

With reference to the following instructions:
http://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UseTheLibrary/Python_Pybel.html

After installing the windows 64-bit version of Openbabel 2.4.1 from http://openbabel.org/wiki/Category:Installation , I have installed openbabel and pybel through pip.

```
>>>pip install pybel
>>>pip install openbabel
```

I am trying to find the molecular weight of a molecule in an sdf format (file name is mol1.sdf present in the same directory)

The python file (test.py) that I've created is as follows:

```
import pybel
mol = pybel.readfile("sdf", "mol1.sdf").next()
print (mol.molwt)
```

Here's what happens in the command prompt:

```
>>> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
mol = pybel.readfile("sdf", "mol1.sdf").next()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'readfile'
```

But according to the sample code in the reference link above, there is an attribute called 'readfile' that reads the file and format. Am I missing something? THanks

Comment: Did you see this: http://forums.openbabel.org/How-to-run-readstring-in-pybel-td4659917.html ?

Comment: @Georgy Thanks for the link! It turns out that I hadn't installed the Python Bindings for the program.

Comment: In this case you can write an answer to your own question and accept it to help people who will encounter the same problem in the future

Answer (score 0):

I found that I made a mistake. It turns out that I hadn't installed the Python Bindings v1.8 for the program.

Answer (score 0):

You installed the "wrong" pybel. For those who use Acaconda, you should search openbabel and install it. After you install openbabel, you should be able to use pybel. Don't search and install pybel directly, pybel itself doesn't work.
You should do the following:
`conda uninstall pybel`, `conda install -c openbabel openbabel`